# Finding the difference between 2 times in hours:min

Tags: php, datetime-format, strtotime

I'm trying to find the difference between 2 times obtained from a sql query:

```
$WakeTime = '05:00:00'; //this is data of today pulled from sql.
$SleepTime = '20:30:00'; //this is data of yesterday pulled from sql.
```

The result I'm looking for is like:
`$Sleep = 24 + $WakeTime - $SleepTime;`
so that `$Sleep` should give `'08:30'`;
Which it's the correct method to get this?

Comment: Why are you adding 24 to wake time before substracting sleeptime?

Comment: Well, since you mention "today" and "yesterday", clearly date should be part of your equation, not just time. Take a look at [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff).

Comment: are you storing date and time or just time?

Comment: @mw509: the person slept y'day. Thus (24Hrs - `$SleepTime`) + `$WakeTime` = `$Sleep`. Here `$WakeTime` is total sleep hours of today, and (24Hrs - `$SleepTime`) are total sleep hours of yday.
@DCR: I am just storing time, not date.

Comment: You really need to store date and time.

Comment: @Bandya you should work on naming your variables better. Am gonna post an answer shortly. Hope it helps but your naming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sleep = gmdate("H:i", 86400 - strtotime($row["SleepTime"]) + strtotime($row["WakeTime"]));
```

This worked consistently. The time, pulled from sql, formats 00:00 Hrs as 1584297000. So just in case the seconds are required by anyone, this is the number you need to subtract from your time. Probably this differs from TimeZone to TimeZone; you will need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, maybe it will be for you.

```
 $result = gmdate("H:i", 86400 - strtotime($SleepTime) - strtotime($Waketime));
```

> output: 08:30

Comment: It works half way through. How can I subtract that output you shown, from 24 hours? I have tried using
`$sleep = gmdate("H:i", strtotime("12 am") - strtotime($SleepTime) + strtotime($Waketime));` but it just doesn't show up the required (24-15:30 = 8:30 hrs)